# Intent for Chat applications

Tags: android

I want to send text from my app, have copied text to clipboard using clipboard manager . Now what I want to do is to create an Intent chooser which only display chat apps like Hike, WhatsApp, sms or any other similar app.

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a SEND intent.

Similar to:

```
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body text");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
```

It'll show all apps, including email. WhatsApp etc. will ignore the subject, while an MMS or email will use it.

Comment: Thank you so much . It worked :).i was trying to do the same. but i think i did some mistake.. your code worked... thanx